# Calling HTTP in A sync Task multiple times in android

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, queue

I want to send some data through an http on a button click, every time the user clicks the button some data should be added to the queue then it will be send through the http, after getting the response i want to remove it from the queue then doing the same with the next items in the queue.

I know how to add items to the queue, and i tried the Async task to call the http.
The problem if the user clicked many times on the button , how can i ensure that next item in the queue won't be called until the http for the first one is done.
And i want the operation to complete if the application was on the background too.

This is the Async Code in the doInBackground Method:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
 try {
 msgResponseIS = getInputStream(generatedLink);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 if (msgResponseIS != null){


      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
       msgResponseIS));
      StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      try {
          while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
       total.append(line);
          }

          setResponseValue(total.toString());

      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }


     return true;}
     else
     return false;
      }
```

Comment: disable the button still you get the response back..

Comment: I can't do that , according to my Application logic, the user can click many times on the button to send the data.But the requests should be added to the queue.And number of requests is undefined.

Comment: run the progress bar still you get the response. When you get the response start the activity again.

Comment: yeh it seems a  good idea, but can i call the async again in the onpost method?

Comment: you can make it onclick of button again..

Comment: What about the queue, i don't know how many time will the user clicks on the button,should i pass it or what?

Comment: on single click of an button send your items to server with progress bar.. again when clicks it ll go.. no need of queue I think.

Comment: by setting flag also you can perform it. as answered by @mamdouh alramadan

Answer (score 0):

when the request is called do `myButton.setEnabled(false);` and when the http request finished you can do

> `myButton.setEnabled(true);`

where `myButton` is the button that calls your async task. this way you can assure that the user can't use this button as long as the async task running.

**EDIT:** other way is to make a `boolean free = ture;` flag. when the button is clicked then just set the flag to `free = false;` and do a check. if the flag is true then http call can be made, else it can't be made.

Comment: HE don't want to disable the button.. any other method

Comment: you can lock the queue with the same flag, so when the flag is free you can pop or(DeQueue) the next element from your queue.

Answer (score 0):

1.On preExecute function you can set the clickable property like this.

 Button.setClickable(false) 

2. After calling doInBackground call the post execute method and set the clickable to true.

 Button.setClickable(true);